# React JS - Pass Provider components methods to this.children

Tags: reactjs

In React can methods be passed to {this.children} in a container consumer model. What I mean to ask is I have a provider component and I need to pass or refer the provider components methods in the child component.

```
export default class ContainerCompo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myHocComponent = null;
  }
  
  methodOne() {
      //some code
  }
  
  methodTwo() {
      //some code
  }

  render() {
    return (
        {this.props.children}
  }
}



export default class InputComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myHocComponent = null;
  }
  
  validate() {
    ContainerCompo.methodOne(param)  
  }

  render() {
    return <InputComponent />
}

// Rendering the components
<ContainerCompo>
    <InputComponent containerMethods={methods of ContainerCompo}/>
</ContainerCompo>
```

I hope my question is clear here, please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a react context.

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

// Create's authentication context to be use anywhere in the app
const ContainerContext = createContext();

export default ContainerContext;
```

Then create a provider for it.

```
export default class ContainerProvider extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.myHocComponent = null;
}

methodOne() {
  //some code
}

methodTwo() {
  //some code
}

render() {
const { children } = this.props;

return (
    <ContainerContext.Provider
        value={{
            container: {
                methodOne: (...params) => this.methodOne(...params),
                methodTwo: (...params) => this.methodTwo(...params)
            }
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </ContainerContext.Provider>
)}}
```

Wrap your App with the provider.

```
import ContainerProvider from './ContainerProvider'
<ContainerProvider>
 <App />
</ContainerProvider>
```

Then create a consumer for the context

```
export default function withContainer(InComponent) {
return function ContainerComponent(props) {
    return (
        <ContainerContext.Consumer>
            {({ container }) => <InComponent {...props} container={container} />}
        </ContainerContext.Consumer>
    );
};
}
```

Then import the consumer and user in your components and you will get the methods as props

```
import withContainer from './ContainerConsumer'
render() {
const { container } = this.props;
return(<div />)
}
export default withContainer(YourComponent);
```

Comment: Will this also help in a reverse flow, I mean to access or trigger a method in Provider from the child ? I am new to React so I don't a clear understand on this flow.

Comment: Yes it will you can use anywhere you want. all you need to do is wrap your component with the withContainer and user this.props.container.yourmethod() to trigger the method.

Comment: I am confused at the last snippet after we import the consumer in our component. Where are we rendering the return from withContainer(YourComponent) ?

Comment: Wherever you want to use the provider methods you need to wrap the component with the withContainer method. For eg. for your InputContainer, instead of default export function put it at the last line of your code and wrap it with withContainer. `export default withContainer(InputComponent)`